# what's the most elegant way to implement this css?

Tags: html, css

I'm enhancing a website where different webparts/tables in a list will need different headers depending on if the table is a placeholder for a job or a break. Currently the list only displays jobs and the css selector is defined like this:

```
.mobile-home-container #mobile-joblist table thead th
```

So what's the most elegant way to implement a table header style based on conditional logic? A job table should keep the same or similar style reference as above but a break table should get a different style reference with a different style implementation. Would you see this defined as 2 separate classes like this?:

- `.mobile-home-container #mobile-joblist table thead .th-job`
- `.mobile-home-container #mobile-joblist table thead .th-break`

Then a class attribute would need to be dynamically bound to the table th based on whether the table was for a job or break?

Comment: these are css selectors, not classes. classes start with a period.

Comment: you really don't need all that extra stuff.. just add the `th-job` and `th-break` classes and then use `.th-job` and `.th-break` in your css. making the selectors as complicated as possible for no good reason certainly isn't elegant.

Comment: Minimalist and precise selectors with minimal nesting is what I try to aim for.  See http://codeguide.co/#css-declaration-order specifically Selectors.

Comment: if the `.th-job` is the default style then you could remove that class altogether. Just have `.th-break` which will override and default styles you want to change

Comment: It really depends on how many table styles you will have and where they converge. If you'll only have these 2 styles, you might call just by the last class. If they have something in commom, maybe the most elegant way is to unite this attributes on .mobile-home-container th, and then split when they are differents. If you have multiple styles you need to understand wich parents are affected by them, unite common characteristics, and define uniques separatelly. But you definetly don`t need to define all path to elements.